# Complex table or ListView layout

Tags: android, listview, tablelayout

I need to implement in my android app a component that displays data like in the image bellow:

[image]

How I can do this? Behavior(scrolling and other) of this table-component must be as a `ListView`. Now I have a two-level `ListView` where `"List 1 label"` and `"List 2 label"` are parent nodes. I want place them to left side. Maybe I must use `TableLayout` where in right column place a `ListView`?

Comment: Have you completed this list, pls tell me i also want to do same...

Comment: I did it by placing child ListView in every row in parent ListView

Answer (score 1):

you can use listview as a main item. on the other side in the getview() method of adapter you can create a dynamic layout depending on the number of items to add to the right side. by going dynamic at runtime depending on the requirement you will be able to generate the ui and place it as a single item. or the other approach you are using is also correct i think, but in that case number of table rows to inflate would get fixed if you are not going for dynamic ui.